# how to exit upon entering negative number

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

This program asks for 100 inputs and sorts inputs in ascending order also calculates the average of all the inputs. I am wondering how do i make it to exit upon entering negative number instead of asking for 100 inputs, and show average .

solved!

Comment: What's wrong with an `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This In Your Code in for loop**

```
cin >> temp;
if(temp >= 0)
    anArray[count] = temp;
else
{

    scores = count;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit the entire program, use [exit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit).

```
if (anArray[count] < 0){
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If you want to break out of the loop, use a [break](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break).

```
if (anArray[count] < 0){
    break;
}
```

Comment: i have tried the second option but the program only exits without calculating the average.